# Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8

Tags: dmesg

Every time I boot my laptop I see this warning and from **dmesg** I get this output:

```
[    2.895604] Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8
[    2.895641]  loop0: unable to read partition table
[    2.895936] loop0: partition table beyond EOD, truncated
```

What does this warning means? Should I be worried? I have an SSD and it seems to be working well.

I saw that RDB means Rigid Disk Block from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga_rigid_disk_block).

When I run **fdisk -l** I get

```
Disc /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Unities: sector of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logic/physic): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimal/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `loop0` device is only 4kB in size, which is 8 blocks of 512 bytes.

The driver for the RDB partition table format tries to read the first 8 kB (16 blocks), because the RDB can be in any of them. While it does that, it reads past the end of the loop device.

This is harmless, and probably went unnoticed because block devices this small are unusual.